# C# Unable to get data in if condition with Test Attribute

Tags: c#, nunit

I am trying to add some texts in txt file format by [Teardown] attribute, it checks whether testcase pass or fail and accordingly it adds data into text file. Pass or fail is detected by if-else condition. Else condition (Passed Test) work fine. But when I am tying to add with Failed test it does not gives result which is expected

For Passed Test -  Result

```
Test Case No.: 12345
Test Details: For test purpose
Start Time: 3/2/2016 3:51:28 PM
End Time: 3/2/2016 3:51:31 PM
Total Time: 0 minutes and 2 seconds
Status: Passed
```

For Failed Test -  Result

```
Test Case No.: 
Test Details: 
Start Time: 3/2/2016 3:49:37 PM
End Time: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
Total Time: -49 minutes and -37 seconds
Status: Failed
```

From the Failed test result, I am not getting below things

1. Test Case No.
2. Test Details:
3. End Time:
4. Total Time:

Below is my code:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
public class TestWithMultipleBrowsers<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{
    static DateTime _timestamp1;
    static DateTime _timestamp2;
    static string _TestNum;
    static string _TestDetails;
[Test]
public void SurfGoogle()
{
    _timestamp1 = DateTime.Now;
    TWebDriver driver = new TWebDriver();
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
  //driver.FindElement(By.Id("q"));
   _timestamp2 = DateTime.Now;
   _TestNum = "12345";
   _TestDetails = "For test purpose";
}


[TearDown]
public void teardown()
{

    string path = (@"..\..\Result\");
    TimeSpan timediff = _timestamp2 - _timestamp1;
    string TotalTime = timediff.Minutes + " minutes and " + timediff.Seconds + " seconds";

    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
    {
        string status = "Failed";

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Failed" + ".txt"), "Test Case No.: " + _TestNum + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Test Details: " + _TestDetails + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Start Time: " + _timestamp1 + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "End Time: " + _timestamp2 + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Total Time: " + TotalTime + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Status: " + status);
    }
    else
    {
        string status = "Passed";

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Passed" + ".txt"), "Test Case No.: " + _TestNum + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Test Details: " + _TestDetails + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Start Time: " + _timestamp1 + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "End Time: " + _timestamp2 + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Total Time: " + TotalTime + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Status: " + status);
    }   
  }
}
```

**To Fail the test you can remove commented part from my code.**

Using NUnit: 2.6.4

Comment: Are you using NUnit 2.6 or 3.0?

Comment: Yes, I am using NUnit 2.6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Test]
public void SurfGoogle()
{
    _timestamp1 = DateTime.Now;  
    _TestNum = "12345";                  <-------
    _TestDetails = "For test purpose";   <-------

    TWebDriver driver = new TWebDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("q"));
  }
}

[TearDown]
public void teardown()
{

    string path = (@"..\..\Result\");
    _timestamp2 = DateTime.Now;          <-------
    TimeSpan timediff = _timestamp2 - _timestamp1;
    string TotalTime = timediff.Minutes + " minutes and " + timediff.Seconds + " seconds";

    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
    {
        string status = "Failed";

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Failed" + ".txt"), "Test Case No.: " + _TestNum + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Test Details: " + _TestDetails + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Start Time: " + _timestamp1 + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "End Time: " + _timestamp2 + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Total Time: " + TotalTime + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Status: " + status);
    }
    else
    {
        string status = "Passed";

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Passed" + ".txt"), "Test Case No.: " + _TestNum + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Test Details: " + _TestDetails + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Start Time: " + _timestamp1 + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "End Time: " + _timestamp2 + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Total Time: " + TotalTime + string.Format(Environment.NewLine) + "Status: " + status);
    }   
  }
```

Try doing this, this might help you.  Charlie is right but I think if you do this will solve your problem.

When NUnit catches an error it comes out of the method from the point where it broke. So the way I did will help to get this data as well. There are three changes and I have marked with this `<-------`

Answer (score 0):

If you remove commenting and the call throws an exception, the following lines are never executed so the values are not set.

Comment: In my comment part my I try to find an  element if element is not found then NUnit gives you an error. Which means it failed. And I am only getting Start Time, which means I am receiving values not all but atleast one.

Comment: And that is the plan if it throws an error, it should show me Result with what I am calling. And that is why I am calling `if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)`

Comment: That's my point. If FindElement throws an exception, your three following lines are never executed, so the member fields are never set.